# Add Category Dynamically ASP.Net 4 MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on creating a blog with ASP.Net 4, MVC 3, Razor and C#.
There are 2 seperate tables. 1 for the actual blog post and a relationship table for categories.
The categories displays as a dropdown.
I want to add the ability to add a new category using Ajax so the user does not lose what they have already entered into the form.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?
Here is what I have right now.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "id", "category_name");
        return View();
    }
```

Razor View

```
@model NPP.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create News Item";
}

<h2>Create News Item</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>News</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.news_title, "Title")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.news_title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.news_title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.news_content, "Content")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.news_content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.news_content)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.news_teaser, "Teaser (optional)")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.news_teaser)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.news_teaser)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category_id, "Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("category_id", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category_id)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance. My layout page includes jquery which I would prefer to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another controler method to return you a list of categories, something like:

```
public JsonResult Categories()
{
  return Json(DB.GetCategorys(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then on the client side, use ajax to get your categories and bind them to your drop down, something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://myserver/myapp/mycontroller/Categories',
  success: function(data) {
       $('#dropCategorys').html('');
       $.each(data, function(i, e) {
           $('#dropCategorys').append('<option value="' + 
              e.category_id + '">' + e.category_name + '</option>');
       }
  }
});
```

This won't save your current selected item, but you can always check that before clearing the list, and reset it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the Category separately via AJAX is not your only option. You could then have a view model like this:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class CreateNewsViewModel
{
    public string news_title { get; set; }
    public string news_content { get; set; }
    public string news_teaser { get; set; }
    public string CategoryViewModel category { get; set; }
}
```

Change your view at the category field:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category, "Category")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.category.id, ViewBag.category_id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.category.name) <!-- only show when creating a new category -->
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category)
</div>
```

Then your action would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult DoCreate(CreateNewsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.category.id == 0)
        {
            // create your new category using model.category.name
        }

        // create an entity from the model and save to your database

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "News"); // do whatever you wish when you're done
    }

    return View("Create", model); // show Create view again if validation failed
}
```

This is more or less off the top of my head so let me know if I bollocks'ed any parts up.